# AS3 cloning an object

Tags: actionscript-3

I've an object contain all types of data

```
var obj1:Object={boo:true,num:0,str:"me",arr:[0,"me2",[0,1]],mc:myMc,obj:{boo:false,num:0,str:"me3",arr:[0,"me4",[0,1]]}};
```

when I clone this object to `obj2` using `ByteArray` with `writeObject(obj1)`& `readObject()`properties, everything is fine except `obj2.mc` (**mc** is a variable that hold the linkage of a movie clip in the library whose class is set to **myMc**) can not be added to stage,

```
addChild(new obj2.mc)
//TypeError: Error #1007: Instantiation attempted on a non-constructor.
```

Help please!!

Comment: shouldnt that be new obj2.mc()?

Comment: Brackets are not necessary when instantiating, this is not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys After 2 hours of experimenting, I came out with this, This is simply the perfect solution... I changed to another way than using `ByteArray`, which is writing each variable in obj2 to its corresponding value in obj1, but faced another problem: when I change arrays in obj2, I found that arrays in obj1 is changed too, this means when writing variables of obj2, arrays were only referenced to that of obj1.. so I had to loop through arrays to write each value in an array individually..

```
var obj1:Object={mc:myMc,bo:true,num:0,str:"me",arr:[myMc,true,0,"me2",[0,1,[0,1]]],obj:{mc:myMc,bo:false,num:0,str:"me3",arr:[myMc,true,0,"me4",[0,1]]}};
var obj2:Object=clone(obj1);

function clone( source:Object ):* {
    var myOBJ:Object=new Object();
    for (var property in source) {
        if (source[property] is Array) {
            myOBJ[property]=clone(source[property]);
        } else {
            myOBJ[property]=source[property];
        }
    }
    return (myOBJ);
}
```

Thanks for all, you've inspired me..

Comment: Hm if you don't need ByteArray, then I would highly recommend using a Factory design pattern :) It would be simply a class that creates such an object of yours and thus it can create identical objects.
Anyways I now understand your idea and your solution, as looping through properties is pretty straight forward and thus correct :) Cheers, the fun is best when you find the solution yourself! :)

Comment: my problem is I am good at scripting in Flash directly, I don't know how to use classes or manipulate them fluently, and I prefer my project to be only 1 file, no external classes files.. that's it..

Comment: Oh I understand.. But my advise would be to invest a week or two to check out how classes work and how to design them - it would get much easier for you :)

Comment: I will take your advice and dive in those classes :D

Answer (score 1):

You cannot duplicate movie clips that easy. It should be something similar to:

```
var objectClass:Class = Object(obj2.mc).constructor;
var instance:MovieClip = new objectClass() as MovieClip;
```

It would be much easier if you pass a Class rather than instance. In your case, that should be `myMc` - the class name of the object that is in the library, right?

If so, you can simply instantiate it directly: `var instance:MovieClip = new myMc();`

The important think to remember is that you don't need to hold reference to an instance, but the class instead!

Comment: yes, the object is in the library and its class is myMc, and yes again I don't need to hold a reference to an instance like mc in obj1, that's why I can use addChild(new myMc) directly, but the reason I referenced myMc to mc is that in my project there are multiple objects obj1,obj2,ob3,etc each contain mc and each mc reference a different MovieClip class, thus when I call addChild(new obj.mc) different outcomes are obtained easily..